# React: Multiple Instances of the same component configured differently

Tags: reactjs

I have made a "drum" functional component that allows the user to enter a number of milliseconds, this starts a loop using that number of milliseconds at the end of the loop a drum sound is played before waiting for the loop again.

This works well but I now need to make a button that will allow the user to add many more drums,

How can I add a second drum component to the app that can be independently configured or removed?

I can't figure out how to do this conceptually? Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: Need some code to demonstrate

Comment: illl make a sandbox once i get home tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-butterfly-nlj9p

Basically, we have a high order component that contains a list of drum "configuration", and renders a drum for each one of them. We can mutate the array to add or remove a drum. Every drum is a separate component, each with its own piece of state

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no code to demonstrate your structure I can only give you the general idea of doing such functionality.

1: In your Drum component accept the milliseconds as props. Let say props.millisecond

2: Create a component that store an array of objects -let call this array as drums- in the state. For example [{id: 0, millisecond: 123}, etc.]. Here id prop is important to both be able to delete the drum and to use in map function.

3: Create a button and textbox that accept millisecond of the drum that will be created. When user clicked to that button add a new object to the this.state.drums array with the given millisecond.

4: In the render function of the component write

```
{this.state.drums.map(d => <Drums key={d.id} millisecond={d.millisecond} />
```

5: If you want to be able to delete a drum write a functionality for that which finds the drum in this.state.drums array by id and delete it from the array.

Hope this is helpful.